# Vector2 not changing kinematic body's position

Tags: godot, gdscript, vector2

I already checked the console to see if it was registering the input, it is. I can't figure out why it won't move.

```
extends Node2D

const WALK_SPEED = 5000
var velocity = Vector2(0,0)

func walk():
    if Input. is_action_pressed("Walk_Up"):
        velocity.y -= WALK_SPEED
        print("debug up")

func _physics_process(delta):
    walk()
```

It is supposed to move the sprite when I press W but nothing is happening other then the text I put in that print statement appearing in the console.
Also Node2D is just the name of the kinematic body I didn't change it from when I changed the type.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the velocity but not calling anything that would use it.

A kinematic body can be moved by setting the velocity and calling one of `move_and_collide()` or `move_and_slide()`, as spelled out in the [docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/tutorials/physics/using_kinematic_body_2d.html#movement-and-collision).

Call either of the two after your `walk()` function:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
  walk()
  move_and_slide(velocity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply not moving the `Node2D`.

Every physics frame you execute `walk`, where if the `"Walk_Up"` action is pressed you update the field variable `velocity`.

And that's it.

*No, changing the variable you declared with name `velocity` has no special meaning, it won't make the `Node2D` move. You can name the variable you declare whatever you want, and it will still not move.*

---

Given that you are working on a `Node2D`, you might want to move it by changing its `position` or `global_position`. For example:

```
extends Node2D

const WALK_SPEED = 5000.0
var velocity = Vector2(0.0,0.0)

func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Walk_Up"):
        velocity.y -= WALK_SPEED

    global_position += velocity * delta
```

*Note: here `WALK_SPEED` units would be pixels per second.*

---

However, since you say Kinematic Body, you might want to use a `KinematicBody2D`, for which the code would be like this:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const WALK_SPEED = 5000.0
var velocity = Vector2(0.0,0.0)

func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Walk_Up"):
        velocity.y -= WALK_SPEED

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
```

Why is it different? Unlike `Node2D`, `KinematicBody2D` is a physics body and it can collide with the environment, and using `move_and_slide` it will move but react to walls (that stop it) and ramps (over which it slides).